# Strange allocation in Julia

Tags: memory, julia

Consider this function

```
function test_function(state, M, new_number)
    M[state..., 1] = new_number
end
```

In my program, I want to run this function multiple times and each time, the arguments would be new (sometimes provided by the user).

To test the memory allocation and speed of this function, I wrote this loop

```
function test_for_loop(loop_num)
    state = [1, 1, 1 ]
    M     = randn(10,10,10,10)
    new_number = 3.0
    for i in 1:loop_num
        test_function(state, M, new_number)
    end 
end
```

Note that `test_for_loop` is written purely to test the efficiency of `test_function` being applied multiple times. In reality, in each application, `state`, `M`, and `new_number` are not known in advance.

I used `@allocated` to find the memory allocation. As I increased `loop_num`, the memory allocation went up. I'm not sure why so I used `--track-allocation`. It turns out `M[state...] = new_number` is taking a huge amount of memory allocation. Can someone please explain why? Why is it allocating extra memory, and how can I reduce the memory allocation such that it doesn't increase with `loop_num`?

Comment: It is not really recommended to write your own loop for benchmarking; it's easy to make mistakes. Instead, use the package BenchmarkTools.jl. It will do warm-up, looping and statistics for you, just call it with `@benchmark test_function($state, $M, $new_number)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is:

```
state = [1, 1, 1]
```

which is a vector, which does not specify how long it is in its type.

Change it to e.g. a tuple (as tuple has known compile-time size):

```
state = (1, 1, 1)
```

and the allocation issue will be solved:

```
julia> function test_for_loop(loop_num)
           state = (1, 1, 1)
           M     = randn(10,10,10,10)
           new_number = 3.0
           for i in 1:loop_num
               test_function(state, M, new_number)
           end
       end
test_for_loop (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @time test_for_loop(10^8)
  0.118755 seconds (2 allocations: 78.188 KiB)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. Is there a link where I can read about what is known at compilation and the impact on speed and memory?

Comment: Also, do `StaticArrays` have the same performance?

Comment: Does it also improve the runtime?

Comment: Using `Tuple` improves runtime dramatically vs `Vector`. Using StaticArrays.jl is in this case not improving things currently on Julia 1.8. However, it potentially could as collection size information is encoded in the type (so in future versions of Julia it is possible that this runs as fast as `Tuple` if proper optimizations in the compiler are in place). What is known at compile time is types of values (but not the values themselves). So compiler only knows information that is encoded in the type.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński, *“Using Tuple improves runtime dramatically vs. Vector.”*. does this depend on the `length` of the `Tuple`? Or is this a ubiquitous role in Julia? (just, e.g., vectors of Floats Vs. tuples of Floats, I mean) ?

Comment: No, it is just that it is a `Tuple` vs `Vector`. Using `Tuple` does not result in allocations and allocations are expensive + lead to GC, which is also expensive.