# Improving memory allocation when the array size is only known at run time

Tags: memory-management, julia

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74787937/strange-allocation-in-julia) but there is an important subtlety.

Consider the following functions

```
using Distributions

function test_function_create_state_list(state_n)
    states = []
    for i in 1:state_n
        push!(states, (sample(1:3), sample(1:3), sample(1:3)))
    end

    return states 
end 

function test_function(state, M, new_number)
    M[state..., 1] = new_number
end

function test_loop(loop_n)
    states = test_function_create_state_list(loop_n)
    M     = randn(10,10,10,10)
    for state in states 
        test_function(state, M, 1.0)
    end 
end
```

Here, `state` is a vector of length k = 3 and M is an array of dimension k+1 = 4. I learned from the linked question that if I knew `k` when I'm writing my code, I can make `state` a `tuple` to improve allocation. However, what if I want to write the following function

```
function test_function_user(states, M)
    for state in states 
        test_function(state, M, 1.0)
    end 
end
```

such that `states` and `M` are provided at run time (by the user)? When I'm writing the program, I would not know the array sizes of `state` and `M`. Is there a way to improve the allocation? I don't know how to use `tuple`s for this, since `tuple`s are not mutable. If I were to use `StaticArrays`, I would need to know the array size when I'm writing the program.